# One to many relationship on the same table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, erd

Here is the situation:-

I have a table called Users. This contains user data for students and tutors as most of the data required is the same.

Having completed the system I am now told that the client would like to be able to assign students to tutors.

Is there a legitimate/ clean way I can create a one to many relationship within a single table, perhaps via a link table?

I've tried to think this through but whatever solution I come up with seems messy.

I would be grateful for any input.

Thanks

Phill

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you tried the following approach?

Make a new table, for example `TutorStudent` (choose a more appropriate name if needed). It should have two columns:

- `Tutor_ID`
- `Student_ID`

Both columns shall be the (composite) primary key, each column will be a foreign key to your `Users` table `User_ID` (I assume this is what you have).

So, if you have a tutor named *Newton* that has two students, *Tesla* and *Edison*, your `Users` table will have something like this:

- **User_ID, Name**
- 1, Newton
- 2, Tesla
- 3, Edison

and your `TutorStudent` table will have following values:

- **Tutor_ID, Student_ID**
- 1, 2
- 1, 3

Relatively simple and doesn't require any modifications to your existing table.

Do take care when deleting users - use the delete cascade feature of your database system or do some maintenance work afterwards so your `TutorStudent` table doesn't go stale when updating/removing your users.

Comment: Excellent! Many thanks Darioo - this is exactly what I was hoping for ;-)

Comment: Hello, I am actually currently having  the same issue as OP! I am using this design but it appears it does not guarantee ONE-MANY relationship.
For example, Table of (1,2) (1,3) (4,3) (2,2) is valid : (

Comment: @Zanko any solution to above? IMO one solution can be to handle the above from application.

Answer (score 0):

My ideal for the same situation

Example: **one book  have many category**:

Basic solution: 
**book** table has recorded book information
**category** table has recored category information ex: 100 documents
**book_category_relation** table has single book (book_id) has category(category_id) 1 book may be have 100 category_id

**Ideal solution**:
First calculate total your category: ex 100 document. Each category equal value 1 bit: max 31 bit  so 100 category we have ceil floor(100%31) = 4  groups

```
category_id = 1  :  1 (1%31) <=>  000000001  group 0 = floor(1/31)
category_id = 2  :  2 (2%31)<=>  000000010 group 0 = floor(2/31)
category_id = 3  :  4 (3%31)<=>  000000100 group 0 = floor(3/31)
category_id = 4   : 8(4%31)<=>  000001000 group 0 = floor(4/31)

...........................
category_id = 31:  2^31(31%31) <=>1000..000 group 0 if moduler 31 equal zero so number group = (31/31 -1)=0;
category_id = 32: 1(32%31) <=> 0000000001 group 1 = floor(32/31)
category_id = 33: 2(33%31) <=> 0000000010 group 1 = floor(33/31)
```

Ok now we add 4 fields in design book table (**group_0,group_1,group_2,group_3**) with int(11) unsigned and add index that fields

if book has category id = n so we can the following calculate formula:

```
bit code = (n%31 ==0)?31: (n%31)
number group field = (n%31==0)?(n/31 -1):floor(n/31)
```

ex: book in category_id = 100 so:

```
bit code = (100%31) =7 <=>2^7 = 128, 
group = floor(100%31) = 3 <=> in group_3
```

so if you need query all book in category_id = 100, query string is:

```
SELECT * FROM book WHERE group_3&128
```

Note: MySQL not index working if bitwise in where.
But you can check in this link:
[Bitwise operations and indexes](https://explainextended.com/2009/10/01/bitwise-operations-and-indexes/?fbclid=IwAR3sPrCnp6q_RufgG_WiT_E-y4kikgpIk7LHq14DeEwKcAkz--HNzEsZeZ8)